# Anyone know a Google Analytics Style jquery Date Selector

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

Here's what Google Analytics has:
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4243418983_354139fd06_o.png

I haven't been able to find one in jQuery anywhere. Anyone seen it? Would be hot right.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

You want the [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker) from jQuery UI.

Comment: +1 this is the closest I know of. Checkout this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range